# xpath match nesting text

Tags: python-3.x, xpath

I want to match the text of the arrow in the picture
[image]

this is my code:

```
data = sel.xpath('//td[text()="Web Reporter"]/following::*/text()')
```

but it is have bug,so who can help me?

Comment: What kind of *"bug"*?

Comment: What's the problem with your current code?

Comment: Can you post a sample xml we can cut and paste?

Comment: `//td[text()="Web Reporter"]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()' I think that's it but I'm not going to type in the xml to see.

Comment: I want to match such as "Allen Kong",what should i do? and can i post a html file to stack overflow,so you can look through html code.

Comment: who can help me ,so i will send html to you by email  to understand easy,so you can look through the html,

Comment: You can get `HTML` from dev console and update your ticket with appropriate sample

Comment: My HTML file has been on the local disk, I want to upload in stackoverflow, so you can see the source code, you can better help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try below `XPath` expressions:

```
//td[text()="Web Reporter"]/following-sibling::td/normalize-space(text()[1])
```

..to get `"Allen Kong..."`

```
//td[text()="Web Reporter"]/following-sibling::td/normalize-space(text()[2])
```

... for `"Bounty Tian..."`

Just change index of `text()[N]` to get required text

Comment: OK ,thank you.it can help me get "Allen Kong",and i still want to  get the same level as <td class="topth2">Web Reporter<.td>,and i give the scores code.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue... Can you clarify little more?

Comment: sorry,I can't upload html,and i give u a link:http://ask.csdn.net/questions/376396,my html in this link,you can see html code in it ,if you can get into this link.thank you.

Comment: Ok. I got your `HTML`. What output you want to get?